# Passing a PHP array of rules to jQuery validator using PHP json_encode

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-validate

Having checked the other posts on this topic I am still unclear on how this should work.. I am generating a PHP array of rules (as form fields are dynamic) to apply the required rule of jQuery validator. Code I am using..

```
$( "#the-form" ).validate({
    <?php echo json_encode($rules);?>
});
```

The `$rules` array looks like this:

```
Array
(
[rules] => Array
    (
        [uName] => Array
            (
                [required] => 1
            )

        [uEmail] => Array
            (
                [required] => 1
                [email] => 1
            )

        [uPassword] => Array
            (
                [minlength] => 5
            )

        [uPasswordConfirm] => Array
            (
                [minlength] => 5
                [equalTo] => #uPassword
            )
    )
)
```

The console is chucking this error:

> **SyntaxError**: invalid property id

Referring to the first item in the json which is printing out like this:

```
{"rules":{"uName":{"required":true},"uEmail":{"required":true,"email":true},"uPassword":{"minlength":5},"uPasswordConfirm":{"minlength":5,"equalTo":"#uPassword"}}}
```

Comment: Not sure but try this, `$( "#the-form" ).validate(<?php echo json_encode($rules);?>);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is with your syntax. You have `{}` around the `<?php  ?>` tags, which is going to end up with your Javascript getting `{{"rules":{ .. }}}`, where you're wanting `{rules:{ .. }}.`

```
$( "#the-form" ).validate({
    <?php echo json_encode($rules);?>
});
```

should be

```
$( "#the-form" ).validate(
    <?php echo json_encode($rules);?>
);
```

in order to work properly.

Comment: Putting quotation marks around the `rules` option absolutely would not break this plugin.  However, yes, the extra set of braces would.

Comment: Yeah should have spotted that. Thanks all